Is it GDPR compliant to require registration to access a privacy policy?
There is currently an issue with Windows operating systems, reputed to be related to Falcon Sensor from CrowdStrike.  From the description of their tool, the question of GDPR compliance can be asked when is has effected companies that may be processing personal data, such as banks:

Falcon Sensor is an agent that CrowdStrike claims "blocks attacks on your systems while capturing and recording activity as it happens to detect threats fast."

CrowdStrike is recorded on the UK Data Privacy Framework List for transfers of personal data to the US under Article 45, and a link is provided to their Privacy Policy.  This requires "Free Registration" to access. [EDIT] It seems this particular instance is more a technical problem than a legal one.  While the question is still valid, it is much less interesting.
Is this compliant with the various GDPR rules that a companies privacy policy is generally used to comply with, particularly those regarding Article 45 transfers to the US?

Can not replicate - I just clicked "reject" and I saw the policy

@Trish Interesting. I do not get the word "reject" in the page I get. I checked visually, and searched the rendered page and the source.  I am in the UK, can I ask where you are? Image of page here

I believe it was the cookie policy I rejected, and what is on your image is below the whole privacy policy. I access from the EU

@User65535 In Firefox I had the same experience that you had. In Chrome I found I could freely access the privacy notice. So this  may be a technical hiccup instead of a conscious decision.

The link provided takes me straight to the full privacy policy on Safari. If your browser or settings is blocking access, that wouldn’t seem to be their problem.

Hmm, failing on my firefox and brave, neither with the closed source DRM extensions.  I wonder if that is the reason.
